# Copying attributed relationship with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, relates

Is there a way using arcpy to copy an attributed relationship and only the attributed relationship ?

I can recreate a non attributed relationship with:

```
arcpy.CreateRelationshipClass_management(arg1,arg2,...)
```

From the doc this function support the argument "attributed" that can take the value "NONE" or "ATTRIBUTED", ok great, but now how to populate this relationship with the two primary key of the two feature class involved ?

I don't want to use `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management` because if we use this function to copy a relationship the function also copy the feature class involved.

Comment: Are you trying to create a RelationshipClass based on an existing RelationshipClass?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Describe to extract all elements of an existing RelationshipClass, and then create a new RelationshipClass using the parameters you choose.

```
import arcpy

# Create a Describe object
#
desc = arcpy.Describe("pathtogdb")

# Print relationship class properties
#

print "%-25s %s" % ("Backward Path Label:", desc.backwardPathLabel)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Cardinality:", desc.cardinality)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Class key:", desc.classKey)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Destination Class Names:", desc.destinationClassName)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Forward path Label:", desc.forwardPathLabel)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Is Attributed:", desc.isAttributed)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Is Composite:", desc.isComposite)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Is Reflexive:", desc.isReflexive)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Key Type:", desc.keyType)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Notification Direction:", desc.notification)
print "%-25s %s" % ("Origin Class Names:", desc.originClassNames)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @klewis. For easier searching in the future, please enter code rather than inserting the code as a screenshot/image.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it only create the relationship, I still have to populate the relationship's table with an update cursor!